# When using the "Yes/ No" field, do you have to pick a default answer?

Tags: cognito-forms

Right now I have to choose "yes" or "no" to be the default and I would like neither to be a default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The Yes/No field is required to have a default value. You can set up a Choice field with the options of 'Yes' and 'No'. This way you can still provide the user with the yes/no choice, but the field will not require a default value.